# How to derive the main depth of binary tree is O(sqrt(N))?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the Second Version of Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C,about the binary tree,there is the description that the mean depth of binary tree is O(sqrt(n)). I try to prove that,but I have no ideas about how to do that,Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Do you mean "mean" depth?

Comment: Oh,I am sorry that I made mistakes in the spelling.Yes,the promblem is about mean/average depth.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider prefect binary tree (always splitting elements into 2):

```
       *
   *       *
 *   *   *   *
* * * * * * * *
```

if I remove gaps and align to left:

```
*
**
****
********
```

You see that each depth level doubles the number of elements in it (in comparison to previous level) so:

```
n = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ...
```

or:

```
n = sum( 2^i ) where i={ 0,1,2, ... ,level-1 }
```

So if you think of it (like binary number with all bits set) its the same as:

```
n = 2^level -1
```

so extracting level from it:

```cpp
n = 2^level -1  // +1
n+1 = 2^level   // log2
log2(n+1) = level
```

where `n` is number of elements and `level` is tree depth.

For different number of splits just the base of the logarithm changes... However for usual real trees the splits are not regular and you need to take into account average number of splits per element instead ...

If your tree's level should be proportional to `O(sqrt(n))` then the elements should form a square (`level^2 = n`) or rectangle so speculating graphically:

```
******
******
******
******
******
******

@@@@@@
*@@@@@
**@@@@
***@@@
****@@
*****@

@
*@@
**@@@
***@@@@
****@@@@@
*****@@@@@@

*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********

          *
       *  *  *
     *  * * *  *
   *  * * * * *  *
 *  * * * * * * *  *
* * * * * * * * * * *
```

so most of elements does not split just first and last in each level splits into 2 except the first level which splits to 3. If I chose a rectangle instead of square then the wider rectangle the more splits on average would be there ...

```
          *
         * *
       *  *  *
     *  * * *  *
   *  * * * * *  *
 *  * * * * * * *  *
*   * * * * * * *   *
```

Comment: Thanks for your graphic.But the problem has limit that the split of each level is 2 at most.Or maybe we did not understand each other very well.

Comment: @Lily mine point was to show you how a `O(sqrt(n))` tree would look like ... the max 2 split is doable you just add one level with additional 2 elements that you remove from last level ...  There are more topologies leading to `O(sqrt(n))` ... see my edit. As we have no info about your tree we can only speculate ... so I show you how to form/derive topology to such depth complexity so you can prove/disprove your case. If you reorder your element into any rectangle with height constantly proportional to tree depth then your depth complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: oh,I got it ,and you give me a new direction about how to solve it.Before I only think the prove may be from the trees themselves.but now if I am clear about the basic topology of the depth complexity O(sqrt(N)),I may derive it in the reverse direction.Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lily yep that was my intention ... graphical approach helps me with complexities and series sum as I often overlook dependence in equation but one look at topology and suddenly its clear ....

Comment: That is really a good idea,and symbolic-graphic combination is usual in mathmetics but I did not try it in CS yet.It gives me much inspiraiton and thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

That's the *average* depth of a binary tree, not a balanced one, by the way, where the *maximum* depth is proportion to `logN`. Paraphrasing the section that's relevant:

> A property of a binary tree that is sometimes important is that the depth of an average binary tree is considerably smaller than `N`.
>
> An analysis shows that the average depth is `O(√N)`, and that for a special type of binary tree, namely the binary search tree, the
>   average value of the depth is `O(logN)`. Unfortunately, the depth can be as large as `n-1`.

To work that out, you can generate all the *possible* trees for a certain value of `N`, then just average those depths.

Comment: I understand why the average depth of the binary search tree is o(logN),and there is a logical relationship between the left and right subtree.But in my opinion,the sitution of binary tree is totally random,that is to say,the depth of binary tree can be as large as n-1,meanwhile it can be as small as O(logN).The probability of each case is the same,and there are n! cases in total.So I need to add up all  theses depths and make the sum divided by n!.Is there any problem in my understanding?

Comment: @Lily, that depends entirely on whether your binary tree is ordered or not. There *are* use cases where ordering doesn't matter but that's not necessarily the case. Your contention that all depths are equally likely may not be true. Consider a three-node ordered tree. There are several depth-3 trees (among them (a at root, b downright of a, c downright of b), (a at root, c downright of a, b downleft of c), (c at root, b downleft of c, a downleft of b)) but only *one* depth-2 one (b at root, a downleft of b, c downright of b).

Comment: I think your *approach* is sound, you just need to decide what the "possibility space" contains for the division. There are fewer possibilities with an ordered tree than an unordered one.

Comment: Thanks for help.I have recognized that some cases may have the same depth,because the range of depth is [log(n),n-1],and there are more basic cases.So I mean the case is equally likely but not the depth.While your help makes me realize that the total cases  are not  n! maybe,and I will compute this more carefully.Thank you very much.